# Connect Postgres Database to BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, multipeer-connectivity

Is it possible to connect a PostgreSQL database with Bigquery?

Comment: With that little information, the answer is "no". To help you, people will need to know what you're currently doing, and what error you're encountering. Please click the "Edit" link (not "Add Comment") and try to explain your problem in more detail. See also [ask].

Comment: Incidentally, it is "Postgres" or "PostgreSQL", never "Postgre".